# Nondimensionalization of Starting Values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation:
$$m*x''(t)=a*x(t)+b*x'(t)$$
And the starting values:

$$x(t_0)=x_0 \text{ and } x'(t_0)=v_0$$

I nondemensionalize this with:
$$\tau=\frac{t}{\bar{t}} \text{ and } y(\tau)=\frac{x(t)}{\bar{x}}$$

For the first starting value i use $$y(0)=\frac{x_0}{\bar{x}}$$, but what do i have to do with the secound starting value? Can i just introduce $\bar{v}$ and use $$y'(0)=\frac{v_0}{\bar{v}}$$ for my nondimensionalized problem?

Comment: Do you know Laplace transform?

Comment: set $$x(t)=e^{\lambda t}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you have
$$
y(τ)=\frac{x(\bar t τ)}{\bar x}
$$
so that in the derivative
$$
y'(τ)=\frac{\bar t}{\bar x}x'(\bar t τ)
$$
and at the initial value
$$
y'(0)=\frac{\bar t}{\bar x}v_0
$$
or if you want, $\bar v=\frac{\bar x}{\bar t}$.